# Multivariate recurrence solve

Tags: recurrence-relations, maple, mathematica

I am currently working on a project and have reduced much of the problem to a single recurrence equation:

$$g(x,y)=1-\frac{1}{6}g(y,x-1)-\frac{1}{2}g(y,x)-\frac{1}{3}g(y+1,x-1)$$
$$g(0,a)=1$$
$$g(a,0)=0$$
When solving the problem out by hand, plugging in an ordered pair (m,n) results in m+n systems of equations which can be solved out (if you don't believe me try it). However, I'm looking for either a closed form for this equation or a way to program a recurrence table. I tried running it in mathematica but it doesn't work because mathematica needs values to recurse on, whereas the problem must be solved using a system of many equations. Any kinda solution would be helpful, whether it be using a program or done by hand. A closed form is preferable but if not possible, a recurrence table at least.

Comment: What is the domain of $x$ and $y?$  Also, the initial conditions are contradictory when $a=0.$

Comment: Have you tried multiplying both sides by $a^xb^y$ and then summing both sides in $x,y$? You'll get a linear PDE for the generating function $G(a,b)$. Assuming you can fix your boundary conditions, it should be easy to solve via method of characteristics.

Comment: @saulspatz when doing the recursion for any values x,y greater than 1, the g(0,0) case is never reached. The domain of x and y is all natural numbers